# AjaxControl Tool kit TabContainer visibility issues

Tags: .net, tabcontainer

I am developing the website in .NET 3.5, VS 2008.
I have a AjaxControlToolkit TabContainer control within Tabpanels I have many usercontrols and inside usercontrol I have my thrid paty Spell Check Utility, while rendering(Page load) the page many times my panel are not visible but when I refresh the page tabs are visible.
Does any body faced any such issue ever?

Answer (score 0):

check is there any thing you are doing in postback check??
secondly do check view state and initial vaule of your control, weatehr it is Visible or not

Comment: the viewstate is on, no I am not doing any postback check and yes I kept the visibility of the Tabcontainer to visible='true' intially.